# Keystore in PKCS12 format seems empty to keytool, but is read by Firefox?

Tags: java, ssl, keytool

I have a problem with a keystore in pkcs12 format, which contains a private key I need to use to authenticate myself (using mutual authentication) to a remote SSL server.  The keystore file can be read perfectly fine by Firefox, and when used, I can access the remote server without problems.

However, my Java program does not work with the keystore file. And if I use keytool to list keys inside the file, it seems empty -- while it is clearly not!

How can I get Java/keytool to see the private key inside the keystore?

Comment: perhaps give some code that you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java can only understand JKS format which stands for Java KeyStore.

Here is a good article to generate the .jks from pkcs12

http://blog.asyd.net/2009/07/how-to-convert-a-pkcs12-to-jks/